# Boolean array in asm

Tags: arrays, assembly

I can create arrays in asm of any size. OK lets create an array of bools. So here is my question: how can i address i(th) bit of my array?

Comment: You should add more details (e.g. what compiler you're using, your target architecture, the way your array is defined, etc.).

Comment: for example, we defined: array: dd 0  (dword = 4 bytes = 32 bits, so we defined memory for bool[32]). But we cant write mov [arrray + x], 1

Comment: I found the thread by searching for how to define such an array. cound some one please post it to here?

Answer (score 0):

Psuedocode (since architecture isn't specified):

accessing i(th) bit :

consider the bools to be a set of flags in a register: where 0 = false and 1 = true

Consider an 8bit machine:

```
            76543210
registerA = 00100100
-----------------------

-----------------------
To access 5th bit      : if ((00100100 & 00100000)>>5) == 1: 5th bit is true; else: false
To access 6th bit      : if ((00100100 & 01000000)>>6) == 1: 6th bit is true; else: false
similarly for nth bit  : if (((number)&(1 << n)) >> n) == 1: nth bit is true; else: false
```

Answer (score 0):

First way - masks:

```
or byte ptr [array+x], %mask% ; %mask% - any value that 1 byte can hold (i.e.: 40h - 1100 0000, 7th & 8th bit will be set on little-endian architecture)
```

Obviously, you can use larger masks with WORD, DWORD (or QWORD on x64).

Second way - [BT*](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/index_b.htm):

```
bts [array], x ; x-th but will be set, previous state will be stored @ CF
```